# Trouble with Responsive Design: Overflow issue when placing image inside a circle

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm currently working on a responsive design, and I'm facing an issue when trying to place an image inside a circle without it overflowing. I have a circular container, and I want the image to fit within the circle without any overflow, especially when the screen size changes.

```css
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10vw;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.circled {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
}

.container {
  width: 80vw;
}

#outer {
  position: relative;
  left: -10vw;
  bottom: 20vh;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Circle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="circled"><img id="inner" src="https://i.postimg.cc/yNNG527Q/pfp.png"><img id="outer" src="https://i.postimg.cc/K8bS99Kw/circle.gif"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I've tried using CSS properties like max-width: 100% and max-height: 100% to ensure the image doesn't exceed the dimensions of the circle, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The image still overflows sadly. I want to achieve a responsive design without relying too heavily on media queries.

Comment: Your container is not a circle, you need to add border-radius 50%. Then why don't you use for .container in your css style sheet background-image:url ('your-link') . for more info [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Comment: Changed to Stack Snippet! Thanks @Paulie_D !

Comment: @Mehdi Thank you so much for your help! I implemented the changes you suggested, and it worked perfectly for my issue. I appreciate your quick and effective solution.

I'm curious, though – just for the sake of exploring different options – is there another way to achieve the same result without using the background of the container? I'm interested in knowing if there are alternative approaches to solving this problem. Thanks!

Comment: You very welcome Andres, glad you had your solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're asking. If you want two images to stack on top of each other perfectly every time, one method is this:

- Stack one on top of the other (like you have) with one being `position: relative;` and the other `position: absolute;`
- Place them both inside a container to group them. If you want to move them at different screen widths, then move this parent container. Moving one parent element is going to be quicker than moving two individual items. Set the parents `position`, which here is set to `position: relative`. This gives the two images a shared common starting point.
- Set the images widths, and then their positions which will be relative to the parent.

As mentioned in the comments, there are multiple ways to achieve what you're trying to do. Using `background-image` is another method, although I find it easier to use another HTML div so I don't have to recall all of the CSS background image properties to accomplish the same thing.

```css
.container {
  width: 80vw;
  position: relative;
}

.circled {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#outer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Circle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="circled">
      <img id="inner" src="https://i.postimg.cc/yNNG527Q/pfp.png">
      <img id="outer" src="https://i.postimg.cc/K8bS99Kw/circle.gif">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```